# Jasper Crosstab - Data Pre-Sorted error

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab, columnsorting

I am using a jasper crosstab. I have data coming in from a database as below

[image]

I have added an order by explicitly to get the data sorted as shown above. The order by consists of multiple columns

Also, I have checked the "Data Pre-Sorted" checkbox

But when I run the report, the pivoted data (which is the Attribute Name as column and reading as its value) have their values coming in as null

However, when I remove the  "Data Pre-Sorted the data comes in fine , but I lose the ordering of the data that I want

Any idea in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presorted data flag requires the data to be sorted according to the crosstab row and column groups, as explained [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#crosstabDataset).  If the requirement is not met, running the report can have unexpected results.

A safer alternative to the presorted flag is setting `order="None"` for all row and column group buckets (or only for specific groups that you don't want to be automatically ordered by the crosstab).  As in

```
            <rowGroup ...>
                <bucket order="None" class="java.lang.Object">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[...]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                ...
```

Comment: Thanks dada67 for replying. So, the order = "None", will keep the data as per the query order and the "Data Pre-Sorted" checkbox can remain unchecked. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct.  The isDataPreSorted offers a small performance improvements in some scenarios, but in most cases order="None" is recommended because it doesn't make assumptions about the data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation dada67